# Какую библиотеку web-парсинга для python выбрать?

Tags: python, grab, lxml, beautiful-soup

Слишком много в сети разных холливаров, и совсем не хочу и здесь читать такое. Сейчас вплотную подошел к выбору, но не знаю, какую библиотеку выбрать: одни ругают и советуют забросить Beautiful Soup, другим нравится русская поддержка, одни советуют Grab, другие восхваляют lxml, в общем новичку очень трудно остановится на чем-то одном. Хотелось бы услышать не хвалебную оду, а действительно сильный довод и четкий пример, в общем надо выбрать, а какой именно - не знаю, на каком остановиться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из собственных ощущений:

- BeautifulSoup удобен, но медленный.
- К lxml нареканий не имею, его и использовал. Работает в разы шустрее, документация, субъективно, лучше чем у BS. Иногда, субъективно, приходилось делать больше телодвижений, чем с BS. Умеет, если надо, использовать BS для парсинга.
- Grab не пробовал.

Answer (score 3):

Если подходить к этому вопросу с точки зрения производительности, то чистый `lxml` (точнее Вам нужен subpackage [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)) в среднем быстрее всех остальных (конечно, очень много вещей может повлиять на скорость парсинга).

Но, я бы не стал однозначно утверждать, что [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) медленный - многое зависит от [парсера, который Вы скажете `BeautifulSoup` использовать](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) - хорошее сочетание это позволить ему использовать `lxml.html` внутри, что сильно поможет в скорости:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
```

Также, например, Вы можете заранее указать `BeautifulSoup`, что не нужно парсить все HTML-дерево, а парсить лишь нужную его часть - делается с помощью [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document).

Также смотрите вот этот топик на SO:

- [Speeding up beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539330/speeding-up-beautifulsoup)

---

С точки зрения удобства API и работы с библиотекой - очень сложно что-то противопоставить `BeautifulSoup` - это, пожалуй, одна из самых удобных библиотек, с которыми мне приходилось работать - отличный и удобный API, множество различного функционала, хорошая документация.

---

Другой важный момент - как парсер поведет себя, если HTML невалидный или сломанный. В этом плане опять же `BeautifulSoup` гибче - например, `html5lib` прощает многие ошибки и не раз Вас выручит, если будете много HTML-парсить:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите библиотеку [pyquery](http://packages.python.org/pyquery/). Это по сути обертка над lxml с jQuery-like синтаксисом.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно столкнулся с точно таким же вопросом и выбор пал на lxml из-за его устойчивости и НЕ-тормознутости при обработке файлов большого размера. Он нормально воспринимает огрехи в структуре xml, чего не скажешь о других. Но однозначно утверждать не буду - другие либы не использовал. Где-то еще на хабре была статейка про парсинг xml на питоне, там приводились доводы в зачет lxml.
Все вышенаписанное сугубо имхо, при несогласии прошу не минусовать :)